# How do I smooth or remove jitter from an exported Graphics3D plot?

Tags: export, graphics3d

I have exported a Graphics3D plot as gif. But the plot shows jitter (You can see the yellow ball shows somewhat slight move around, which is expected to be still). How does this happen and how to get rid of this jitter?

This is the codes:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.1], EdgeForm[None], 
    Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2}}, 1]}, {Yellow, 
    Sphere[{0, 0, -2}, 0.1]}, {Dashed, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 0}}]}, 
   GeometricTransformation[{Red, Arrowheads[0.03], 
     Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 1, 0}}, 0.005]]}, 
    RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -2}]]}, 
  ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1},
  Boxed -> False], {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]

pics = Table[
   Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.1], EdgeForm[None], 
      Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2}}, 1]}, {Yellow, 
      Sphere[{0, 0, -2}, 0.1]}, {Dashed, 
      Arrow[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 0}}]}, 
     GeometricTransformation[{Red, Arrowheads[0.03], 
       Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 1, 0}}, 0.005]]}(*{Black,Arrow[{{0,
      0,-2},{0,1,0}},.001]}*), 
      RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -2}]]}, 
    ViewCenter -> Automatic,
      Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500], {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi], 
    0.1 \[Pi]}];

Export["F://pics.gif", pics]
```

This is the exported figure
[image]

Comment: you are discretising  Θ in your table from -π to π which means that at those two points you get two frames rather than one. Try `{Θ, -π + 0.1 π, π, 
    0.1 π}` instead

Comment: @gpag, I've tried. The jitter is still present. Even in the Manipulate, which is in absence of the discretization, the plot still jitters around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a fixed `PlotRange` like this :

```
pics = Table[
   Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.1], EdgeForm[None], 
      Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2}}, 1]}, {Yellow, 
      Sphere[{0, 0, -2}, 0.1]}, {Dashed, 
      Arrow[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 0}}]}, 
     GeometricTransformation[{Red, Arrowheads[0.03], 
       Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 1, 0}}, 0.005]]}(*{Black,Arrow[{{0,
      0,-2},{0,1,0}},.001]}*), 
      RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -2}]]}, 
    ViewCenter -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2.3, 0}}, 
    ImageSize -> 500], {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi], 0.1 \[Pi]}];
```

[image]